# Nuget package and its dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to figure out why, on installing a nuget package, my project is sometimes updated with references to all the packages dependencies, and sometimes not, depending on the package installed. Specifically, it's a package that I created that gives the unwanted install behavior, while other common packages give the expected/desired behavior.

My problem package is built with an sdk-style project, and targets net48 as well as net5.

The target project for the package install is net48 and the project style is the non-sdk type.

When I install a popular package like log4net or newtonsoft.json, I get only a single entry in the packages.json, and one (newtonsoft) or three (log4net) new  entries in the csproj.  These packages must have more dependencies than that, right?  But they aren't reflected in these configuration files.

But when I install a package that I created, both the packages.json and csproj are udpated with MANY dependencies.  Here is a partial list:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.6.17.0
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.6.17.0
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.6.17.0
System.CodeDom.6.0.0
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.6.17.0
System.IO.4.3.0
System.Management.6.0.0
System.Runtime.4.3.0
```

Why is this happening?
I've read that I could use the dependency behavior "Ignore Dependencies" on the install, but I didn't need to on the common packages, so why would I here?

Comment: Why must they? Popular libraries like that intentionally use as few dependencies as possible

Comment: A peek at log4net source shows that it has usings for system.io.  But when I install log4net for use in a framework 4.8 project, it does not generate a reference  to package system.io in my project's packages.config. (or any other place).  When I install my own package into the same project, it generates a reference to package system.io.  I don't understand why this behavior differs.